# Send data To SQL Server Through Socket

Tags: sql, sockets

I have been trying for days now to connect to my SQL Server through a socket. I can't find what is wrong.

I think I did a correct setup of my sql server, I am able to connect to it from ever the Server manager or Visual Studio with the same connection info that I am using in my Socket.
It works everytime but with the socket. The socket can connect but when it send a string to the server, the SQL Server Logs gives me this:
"length specified in netword packet payload did not match number of bytes read; the connection have been closed
Error: 17836, Severity 20, State 17".

Here is the Socket code I use. It Took it from Microsoft Socket Server/client example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "ClientMFC.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")



using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    //WSADATA is a struct that is filled up by the call 
    //to WSAStartup
    WSADATA wsaData;


    //WSAStartup initializes the program for calling WinSock.
    //The first parameter specifies the highest version of the 
    //WinSock specification, the program is allowed to use.
    int wsaret=WSAStartup(0x101,&wsaData);

    //WSAStartup returns zero on success.
    //If it fails we exit.
    if(wsaret!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;   // will hold the destination addr  

    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;          // host byte order
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(2433);   // short, network byte order
    dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.100.17.114");
    memset(&(dest_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);  // zero the rest of the struct
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // do some error checking!


   // Connect to server.
    int iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    const char *   toto   = "<connectionString>Data Source=10.100.17.114,2433;ENCRYPT=false;Initial Catalog=MetricsLocal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=XXX</connectionString>";

    char *SendBuf = (char*)malloc(strlen(toto) * sizeof(char));
    // convert to network byte ordering. This is important for running on the ps3 and xenon
    for(INT BufIndex = 0; BufIndex < strlen(toto); ++BufIndex)
    {
        SendBuf[BufIndex] = toto[BufIndex];//htons(toto[BufIndex]);
    }


    int BytesSent           = send(ConnectSocket, SendBuf , strlen(SendBuf),0);

    printf("BytesSent = %d, Supposed = %d\n", BytesSent, strlen(toto));


    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    return nRetCode;
}
```

Note that I have hidden my password.
This code should be really easy for you to try. Just add ws2_32.lib in your linker additional dependancies.
I am really really stuck with this.
I am pretty sure the size is correct. I also coded a Socket server to check what I receive and it seems correct.
Ideas:
- Do I need a header not described anywhere?
-Do I have a special settings to do somewhere ?
My telnet connection tells me my port is open and ready.<

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you've gotten this far, why don't you try firing up wireshark and comparing your packets to native SQL server packets from say ADO.NET?

Comment: I really can't get anything readable out of this tool !

Comment: Can you tell me what I should invest my attention in Wireshark ? It is a bit TMI as it is !